# Mvvm binding throw

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a project, that uses Mvvm Light, and during a Thread, the application throws an exception.

> Must create dependencysource on same thread as the dependencyobject.

I use a `Canvas`, with `PolyLine`

```
<Canvas Name="canvas1" SizeChanged="canvas1_SizeChanged" >
 <Polyline Points="{Binding SegmentPoints}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.5"/>
</Canvas>
```

In my ViewModel, I have a Property called `SegmentPoints`

```
private PointCollection segmentPoints;
public PointCollection SegmentPoints
        {
            get { return segmentPoints; }
            set {segmentPoints = value;    
                RaisePropertyChanged("SegmentPoints");
            }
        }
```

I have a `Thread`, which runs in the background.

```
var p = new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartMeassureThread);
Thread t = new Thread(p);
t.Start(package);
```

In `StartMeassureThread` I call the `updatePointCollection` function:

```
segmentPoints = new PointCollection();
...somecode
RaisePropertyChanged("SegmentPoints");
```

And it throws an exception:

> ArgumentException was unhandled by user code.

Inside

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me out? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change UI from the thread other then UI thread. To synchronize you can use `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI` method provided by MVVMLight:

```
var value = CreateSegmentPoints();
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(()=> SegmentPoints = value);
```

Comment: I have initialized the DispatcherHelper in the static App contructor, also added your code, but it throw the exception again. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the background thread sets the SegmentPoint and the View is bound to this property, the background thread will be used to change the UI. This will cause an exception because only the UI-thread is allowed to update the UI.

A quick fix could be made by switching to the Dispatcher of the View in the ViewModel's RaisePropertyChanged. To do that you need to capture the UI thread somehow. E.g., by passing it to the constructor when attaching the ViewModel to the View.

For more dynamic situation you might want to subscribe the View's DataContextChanged and set the correct thread there.